# PyTorchでCUDAが使えない

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, pytorch

PyTorchでCUDAを使って計算しようとしたところ、下記エラーが吐かれてしまいました。

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #4 'mat1'
```

このエラーの対処方法をご教授していただけないでしょうか。
コードは下記の通りで、MNISTの画像分類問題を簡単なニューラルネットワークで解こうと思っておりました。
一応テンソルとモデルをすべてGPUに送っているつもりでしたが、うまくいきませんでした。

```py
import torch
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")
print(device)



# 手書き数字の画像データMNISTをダウンロード
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, data_home=".")

X = mnist.data / 255  # 0-255を0-1に正規化
y = mnist.target

# MNISTのデータセットの変更により、ラベルが数値データになっていないので、
# 以下により、NumPyの配列の数値型に変換します
import numpy as np
y = np.array(y)
y = y.astype(np.int32)

# 2. DataLoderの作成
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# 2.1 データを訓練とテストに分割（6:1）
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=1/7, random_state=0)

# 2.2 データをPyTorchのTensorに変換
X_train = torch.Tensor(X_train).to(device)
X_test = torch.Tensor(X_test).to(device)
y_train = torch.LongTensor(y_train).to(device)
y_test = torch.LongTensor(y_test).to(device)

# 2.3 データとラベルをセットにしたDatasetを作成
ds_train = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
ds_test = TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

# 2.4 データセットのミニバッチサイズを指定した、Dataloaderを作成
# Chainerのiterators.SerialIteratorと似ている
loader_train = DataLoader(ds_train, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
loader_test = DataLoader(ds_test, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

# 3. ネットワークの構築
from torch import nn

model = nn.Sequential().to(device)
model.add_module('fc1', nn.Linear(28*28*1, 100))
model.add_module('relu1', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('fc2', nn.Linear(100, 100))
model.add_module('relu2', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('fc3', nn.Linear(100, 10))

print(model)

# 4. 誤差関数と最適化手法の設定
from torch import optim

# 誤差関数の設定
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# 重みを学習する際の最適化手法の選択
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# 5. 学習と推論の設定
# 5-1. 学習1回でやることを定義します
def train(epoch):
    model.train()  # ネットワークを学習モードに切り替える

    # データローダーから1ミニバッチずつ取り出して計算する
    for data, targets in loader_train:
        data = data.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()  # 一度計算された勾配結果を0にリセット
        outputs = model(data)  # 入力dataをinputし、出力を求める
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)  # 出力と訓練データの正解との誤差を求める
        loss.backward()  # 誤差のバックプロパゲーションを求める
        optimizer.step()  # バックプロパゲーションの値で重みを更新する

    print("epoch{}：終了\n".format(epoch))

# 5-2. 推論1回でやることを定義します
def test():
    model.eval()  # ネットワークを推論モードに切り替える
    correct = 0

    # データローダーから1ミニバッチずつ取り出して計算する
    with torch.no_grad():  # 微分は推論では必要ない
        for data, targets in loader_test:
            data = data.to(device)
            targets = targets.to(device)

            outputs = model(data)  # 入力dataをinputし、出力を求める

            # 推論する
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)  # 確率が最大のラベルを求める
            correct += predicted.eq(targets.data.view_as(predicted)).sum()  # 正解と一緒だったらカウントアップ

    # 正解率を出力
    data_num = len(loader_test.dataset)  # データの総数
    print('\nテストデータの正解率: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(correct,
                                                   data_num, 100. * correct / data_num))

# 学習なしにテストデータで推論してみよう
test()

# 6. 学習と推論の実行
import time
t1 = time.time() 

for epoch in range(10):
    train(epoch)
test()
```

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

手元の環境で試していましたが

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model.add_module('fc1', nn.Linear(28*28*1, 100))
model.add_module('relu1', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('fc2', nn.Linear(100, 100))
model.add_module('relu2', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('fc3', nn.Linear(100, 10))
model.to(device)
```

とするとうまく動きました